# Why does AVIStreamRead read nothing?

Tags: c++, avi, vfw

I'm writing a simple AVI loader to get each frame from an AVI file and save it to an OpenGL texture. I'm using VFW, and `AVIStreamRead` isn't returning anything. This is my code that grabs each frame:

```
void CVideoControl::SetFrame(long frame)
{
    HRESULT result;
    long bytes, samples;

    //Update variables
    m_currentFrame = frame;
    m_lastFrameChangeMS = gGlobalData->GetLastFrame();

    //Get the frame
    result = AVIStreamRead(m_aviStream, m_currentFrame, 1, m_inputTexture, m_videoAdjustedWidth * m_videoAdjustedHeight * 3, &bytes, &samples);
    if(FAILED(result))
        return;

    //Decompress the stream
    if(ICDecompress(m_decompressor, 0, m_inFormat, m_inputTexture, m_outFormat, m_outputTexture) != ICERR_OK)
        return;

    //Draw it to the OpenGL texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_videoOutputTexture);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, m_videoAdjustedWidth, m_videoAdjustedHeight, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_outputTexture);
}
```

The variable `bytes` has a value of 2740, and `samples` is 1. However, `m_inputTexture` is empty. It's not a bad pointer or anything, its just... empty. `AVIStreamRead` doesn't return any errors. In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the only mention of data not being read is:

> If lpBuffer is NULL, this function does not read any data;

But `lpBuffer` isn't NULL. I would post more code, but it's scrambled all over the place. There are no other apparent errors anywhere else, and the debugger shows all the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

Different AVI files are encoded using different codecs.  Perhaps the file you're trying to decode doesn't have a codec that can be handled by vfw.

Also I would start with some working sample code and slowly modify it to fit my needs.  There are just too many details when video is involved, which make pure documentation mostly useless.

Comment: I've tried multiple videos. When I use `ICLocate` to find a decompressor, it succeeds with valid data. Everything runs fine until here. I'll look around for some samples but there aren't very many good ones.